# nginx with double conditions (ipgeo + useragent)

Tags: nginx, ip-geolocation

we're deploying an international website using different TLDs.

We use the ipgeo module from nginx to detect the user location and we make redirects if are needed.

But we found some problems with the bots, so we want to prevent redirection in that case.

For that, we will need to use double conditions in the nginx config and this isn't supported.

Can we use a different solution? Thanks

This is a code snippet from the UK configuration, I think that is self-explain.

```
    if ($http_user_agent !~* "google|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot") {

    # goto global site
      if ($geoip_city_continent_code != "EU") {
        rewrite ^ https://xxxx.us$request_uri permanent;
      }

    # goto EU site
      if ($geoip_city_country_code != "GB") {
        rewrite ^ https://xxxx.eu$request_uri permanent;
      }


    # remains in UK site
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work with your system. Please give a look

```
if ($http_user_agent !~* "google|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot") {

# Here you can setup a value which will skip redirect. 
set $geoip_city_continent_code="UK";


}

# goto global site
      if ($geoip_city_continent_code != "EU") {
        rewrite ^ https://xxxx.us$request_uri permanent;
      }

    # goto EU site
      if ($geoip_city_country_code != "GB") {
        rewrite ^ https://xxxx.eu$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for us came from @Kernelv5.

Additionally, it adds more flexibility to the redirects without adding complexity.

Thanks

```
  set $continent "${geoip_city_continent_code}";
  set $country "${geoip_city_country_code}";

  if ($http_user_agent ~* "google|yahoo|bingbot|baiduspider|yandex|yeti|yodaobot|gigabot|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot") {
    set $continent "US";
    set $country "US";
  }

  if ($country = "GB") {
    rewrite ^ https://xxxx.co.uk$request_uri permanent;
  }

  if ($continent = "EU") {
    rewrite ^ https://xxxx.eu$request_uri permanent;
  }
```